# Use reduce method in dart to group consecutive elements in the list like in Javascript

Tags: dart

I have following codes in javascript

```
var ArrayLogs = [1, 3, 5, 4, 9, 11, 0, -4, -10];
var newLogArrays = [];
 ArrayLogs.reduce(function(result, value, index, array) {
              if (index % 2 === 0){
                newLogArrays.push(array.slice(index, index + 2));
              }
              return newLogArrays;
            }, []);
```

Above method outputs:
**[[1,3],[5,4],[9,11],[0,-4],[-10]]**

I am looking equivalent code in `Dart`, I know there is `reduce` method in dart as well, but I am not sure how to use to get similar result as javascript.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What result do you want? I don't know JavaScript.

Comment: @julemand101 i updated my original post with javascript output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to do it using Dart only, you can do something like the following:

```dart
void main() {
  final arrayLogs = [1, 3, 5, 4, 9, 11, 0, -4, -10];

  final result = arrayLogs.fold<List<List<int>>>([], (list, element) {
    if (list.isEmpty || list.last.length > 1) {
      return list..add([element]);
    } else {
      return list..last.add(element);
    }
  });

  print(result);
  // [[1, 3], [5, 4], [9, 11], [0, -4], [-10]]
}
```

I am sure there are some packages which can do this more automatically or cleaner.